# What is the UNSECURED keyword used in FatFractal server extension declarations?

Tags: custom-backend

For server extension declarations in FFDL, I have seen variations both including and excluding the `UNSECURED` keyword as follows:

```
CREATE EXTENSION /ActivateUser UNSECURED AS javascript:require ('scripts/RegistrationExtension').activateUser();

CREATE EXTENSION /ChangePassword AS javascript:require ('scripts/PasswordExtension').changePassword();
```

What is the `UNSECURED` keyword used for? Most examples I have found simply exclude it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, a user needs to be logged in to hit a server extension, but when you specify `UNSECURED` this restriction is lifted and anonymous users can trigger the extension.